# Multiple Script serially or simultaneously in Loadrunner TruClient?

Tags: loadrunner, truclient

Is there any ways that I can run multiple script **serially** or **simultaneously** by scheduling or other process in TruClient?

Like I have 100 scripts on a single project. So if I need to run automation test, I don't want run all the scripts manually. Sometimes I need run 50 scripts among them. So is there any good solution to optimize this work load?

Comment: What do you mean "run manually"? Don't you run them through the controller?

Comment: Actually you are right. I am new user. Discovered the "Controller" today. Btw thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You need training.  Your management is setting you up to fail without training or a mentor in this field.

Comment: @JamesPulley, Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I am the only person in my company who is studying this. So need to struggle a bit. :)

Comment: Your manager needs to send you to confirm your core, non tool related skills, send you to training and provide you a mentor.  If they are unwilling to do this then they are not interested in your success, only in your ability to bill.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jenkins, you can use the HPE Application Automation Tools to automate your performance testing using TruClient.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HPE+Application+Automation+Tools

Comment: Actually the "Controller" can give me the solution. Btw thanks the suggestion.

Comment: There's no conflict. The Jenkins plugin also leverages Controller, adding the ability to schedule tests or run them in CI.